# kubernetes daemonset fails to pull docker image from the cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am having issues with my Kubernetes cluster daemonSet. I have deployed this yaml file on my cluster. It looks like the daemonSet is failing to pull the docker image from the registry.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: oci-la-fluentd-daemonset
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: oci-la-fluentd-logs
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oci-la-fluentd-logs
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oci-la-fluentd-logs
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: oci-la-fluentd-serviceaccount
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      # Uncomment the following section if a secret is associated to pull the image
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: oci-la-fluentd-logs
          # Replace this value with actual docker image url
          image: iad.ocir.io/kobie/oke_logging/fluentd_oci_la
          # Replace this value with desired value for image pull policy
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: awx_lower
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
```

As you could see I have attached the secrets on my yaml files to pull the image.

This is the error message. This is what I get on the cluster when I look at the pods.

```shell
Failed to pull image iad.ocir.io/kobie/oke_logging/fluentd_oci_la:latest rpc error: code = Unknown desc denied: Anonymous users are only allowed read access on public repos
```

Comment: You are on prem k8s or on OCI? You try to pull from Oracle Container Image Registry, correct?
The error related to OCI Registry. Unfortunately no public access to solution https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2764985_1.html